# Decorate class-method with class-decorator

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to decorate class method using class-decorator. For example

```
class MyDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self,param1):
        self.param1 = param1
        # do some action with param1

    def __call__(self,func):
        def wrapped(*args,**kwargs):
             print "in wrapper:"
             func(*args,**kwargs)

        return wrapped
```

and my some class:

```
class A:
    @MyDecorator("Blablabla")
    def func1(arg1,arg2,arg3):
         print (arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

but when I do the next action:

```
a = A()
a.func(1,2,3)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: func1() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: Are you calling `a.func` or `a.func1`?

Answer (score 2):

```
class A:
    @MyDecorator("Blablabla")
    def func1(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        print (arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

You need to add the self argument to your function.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to write your `func1` method without a first `self` argument, you need to drop this argument in the decorator:

```
def __call__(self, func):
    def wrapped(obj, *args, **kwargs):
         # obj is just ignored
         print "in wrapper:"
         func(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is quite the same as using `@staticmethod`: when calling `a.func1`, `a` is passed as first argument, but this argument is removed by the decorator.

Comment: This is true, but that's not what is causing the error that OP is getting.

Comment: @AndrewSledge Both solutions are valid and fix the OP's error, although with yours the code will certainly be easier to read. Mine is  only useul if you need to implement `@staticmethod` behaviour.