# Decorate class method with another class method, conditionally

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I think this is an extension to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787474/decorate-class-method-with-class-decorator)

**Background**

Working with python 2.7, I have a class

```
class Report(object):
  def translate_report(self, report_entity):
    ... # Process report_entity dictionary and return results

# But there is a legacy report class too
class Legacy_Report(object):
  def translate_report(self, legacy_report_entity):
    ... # Process report_entity dictionary in different way and return results
```

The `report_entity` is a dictionary dumped as string in a text file. The dictionary objects vary depending upon `Report` and `Legacy_Report`.

**Requirement**

I'll recreate the object instance with this dictionary and call `translate_report`. The calling method would be agnostic whether the entity is legacy version or the new one.

**My approach**

```
class Legacy_Report(object):
  @staticmethod
  def _legacy_translation(legacy_report_entry):
    ... # Process
    return legacy_report_entry

  def __call__(self, underlying_function):
    def wrapper_func(self, report_object):
      if 'legacy' in report_object.keys():
        return Decorator._legacy_translation(report_object)
      else:
        return underlying_function(self, report_object)
    return wrapper_func

class Report(object):
  @Legacy_Report()
  def translate_report(self, report_entity):
    ... # Process report_entity 
    return report_entity
```

**The Question**

While this works, is this the right way to achieve this ?

Maybe decorator at some other level or some better pythonic way ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use inheritance.

```
class Report(object):
    def translate_report(self, report_entity):
        ... # Process report_entity dictionary and return results


class Legacy_Report(Report):
    def translate_report(self, legacy_report_entity):
        ... # Process the legacy report differently
```

Comment: That would defeat the purpose. By OOPS paradigm, they should not inherit as they are unrelated. Plus, the calling for `translate_report` should be conditional based upon the `report_entity` contents

Comment: I'm assuming the class contains something *besides* the `translate_report` method; otherwise, what's the point of the class in the first place?

Comment: Sort of. The legacy report class is basically just an extension of `__dict__` with very few additional methods. Newer report class is really fancy though :)

Comment: Any pythonic solution, anyone ??