# Class decorators for methods in classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, decorator, class-decorator

How do class decorators for methods in classes work? Here is a sample of what I've done through some experimenting:

```
from functools import wraps


class PrintLog(object):

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args):
            print('I am a log')
            return func(*args)
        return wrapped


class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, rs: str) -> None:
        self.ter = rs

    @PrintLog()
    def baz(self) -> None:
        print('inside baz')


bar = foo('2')
print('running bar.baz()')
bar.baz()
```

And this works perfectly fine. However, I was under the impression that decorators do not need to be called with `()`, but when I remove the brackets from `@PrintLog()`, I get this error:

```
    def baz(self) -> None:
TypeError: PrintLog() takes no arguments
```

Is there something I am missing/do not understand? I've also tried passing in a throwaway arg with `__init__()`, and it works.

```
class PrintLog(object):

    def __init__(self, useless):
        print(useless)

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args):
            print('I am a log')
            return func(*args)
        return wrapped

class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, rs: str) -> None:
        self.ter = rs

    @PrintLog("useless arg that I'm passing to __init__")
    def baz(self) -> None:
        print('inside baz')
```

Again, this works, but I don't want to pass any argument to the decorator.

**tl;dr:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787474/decorate-class-method-with-class-decorator) in python 3.x.

Help appreciated!

Comment: This question duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416947/python-class-based-decorator-with-parameters-that-can-decorate-a-method-or-a-fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class decorators accept the function as a subject within the `__init__` method (hence the log message), so your decorator code should look like:

```
class PrintLog(object):

    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self):
        @wraps(self.function)
        def wrapped(*args):
            print('I am a log')
            return self.function(*args)
        return wrapped
```

Sorry if this doesn’t work, I’m answering on my mobile device.

**EDIT:**

Okay so this is probably *not* what you want, but this is the way to do it:

```py
from functools import update_wrapper, partial, wraps


class PrintLog(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func
    
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        """Support instance methods."""
        return partial(self.__call__, obj)

    def __call__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        @wraps(self.func)
        def wrapped(*args):
            print('I am a log')
            return self.func(*args)
        return wrapped(obj, *args)


class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, rs: str) -> None:
        self.ter = rs

    @PrintLog
    def baz(self) -> None:
        print('inside baz')


bar = foo('2')
print('running bar.baz()')
bar.baz()
```

The decorator has to have the `__get__` method defined because you're applying the decorator to an instance method. How would a descriptor have the context of the `foo` instance?

Ref: [Decorating Python class methods - how do I pass the instance to the decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365701/decorating-python-class-methods-how-do-i-pass-the-instance-to-the-decorator)

Comment: It doesn't. `I am a log` is not printed, and neither is `inside baz`

Comment: Yep this works - and I did read up a bit about the `__get__` method, so I think I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a big picture you're missing.

```
@decorator
def foo(...):
   function_definition
```

is almost identical (except for some internal mangling) to

```
temp = foo
foo = decorator(temp)
```

It doesn't matter what the decorator is, as long as it can act like a function.

Your example is equivalent to:

```
baz = PrintLog("useless thing")(<saved defn of baz>)
```

Since `PrintLog` is a class, `PrintLog(...)` creates an instance of `PrintLog`.  That instance has a `__call__` method, so it can act like a function.

Some decorators are designed to take arguments.  Some decorators are designed not to take arguments.  Some, like `@lru_cache`, are pieces of Python magic which look to see if the "argument" is a function (so the decorator is being used directly) or a number/None, so that it returns a function that then becomes the decorator.

Comment: So are you saying that class decorators need the `()` to instantiate them? Or should i do something like `PL = PrintLog(); @PL`?

Comment: No.  I'm saying you need to read the documentation for the decorator before using it, and not make assumptions.  Some decorators are functions and don't take arguments.  Some are classes with a `__call__` method and do need arguments.

Comment: Alright. I think I get why i had that problem now, but is there any helpful documentation for decorators and such?

Comment: Look up "Python decorator" in your favorite search engine and you'll find all sorts of information at whatever level your looking for.